# Why does my code give me the wrong result when adding negative numbers in Python?

Tags: python, sum

```
def hourglassSum(arr):
     totSum = 0
     sum = 0
   for j in range(4):
     for i in range(4):
        sum = arr[j][i] + arr[j][i+1] +arr[j][i+2]
        print(sum)
        if (sum > totSum):
            totSum = sum
   return totSum
```

the purpose of my program is to find some elements from an array and add them together. if one sum is greater that other sum then return the maximum sum. The code works for positive numbers. But doesn't work for negative numbers. can anybody help me explain why?

Comment: You're not summing anything over the array..?

Comment: Please edit your code for greater clarity

Comment: I believe you want to start the totSum at `float('-inf')`

Comment: I guess the problem is in the "if float(sum) > float(totSum):" are you comparing the values? Or their absolutes?

Comment: I added the float because i saw it online. i don't actually need it.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because the sum of negative numbers is less than `0`. Meanwhile, `totSum` starts off being `0`, which is why `sum > totSum` ends up never being `True`.

Here's one way to fix it:

```
import math
def hourglassSum(arr):
    totSum = -math.inf
    for j in range(4):
        for i in range(4):
            sum = arr[j][i] + arr[j][i+1] +arr[j][i+2]
            if (sum > totSum):
                totSum = sum
   return totSum
```

Of course, there's always a one-liner for this sort of thing:

```
def hourglassSum(arr):
    return max(arr, key=sum)
```